# Why was I leaving orange ghosts behind?

Tags: lost-planet-2

Yesterday, I was playing a game online, and while I was respawning it said something about showing zombies. After spawning, I noticed that every couple of seconds I was leaving orange ghosts, or perhaps "zombies", of where I was then. I died pretty quickly though, and never found out why.

Does anybody know why that was happening?

Answer (score 3):

It's probably one of the upgrades for the shield: the locater of the other team can see the orange ghosts, making it easier to find you.